# WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR Error after login to sugarCRM from java Axis 1.4

Tags: java, sugarcrm, axis

I want to import data from java web application to sugarCRM. I created client stub using AXIS and then I am trying to connect, it seems it is getting connected, since I can get server information. But after login, it gives me error while getting sessionID:

Error is: "faultString: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it."

Here is my code:

```
private static final String ENDPOINT_URL = " http://localhost/sugarcrm/service/v3/soap.php";

java.net.URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(ENDPOINT_URL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            System.out.println("URL endpoing creation failed. Message: "+e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();   
        }

> System.out.println("URL endpoint created successfully!");
        Sugarsoap service = new SugarsoapLocator();
        SugarsoapPortType port = service.getsugarsoapPort(url);

        Get_server_info_result result = port.get_server_info();
        System.out.println(result.getGmt_time());
        System.out.println(result.getVersion());
        //I am getting right answers

        User_auth userAuth=new User_auth();
        userAuth.setUser_name(USER_NAME);
        MessageDigest md =MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        String password=convertToHex(md.digest(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes()));
        userAuth.setPassword(password);

        Name_value nameValueListLogin[] = null;

        Entry_value loginResponse = null;
        loginResponse=port.login (userAuth, "sugarcrm",nameValueListLogin);

        String sessionID = loginResponse.getId(); // <--- Get error on this one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nameValueListLogin could be be from a different document context (coming from a different source). See if [this](http://wwv.comanswer.com/question/org-w3c-dom-domexception-wrong-document-err-a-node-is-used-in-a-different-document-than-the-one-that-created-it) link helps.

You may need to get more debugging/logging information so we can see what nameValueListLogin consists of and where it is coming from.

Comment: I checked code and found username was incorrect, so that solved the problem, I could login and get sessionId successfully. The error seems really misleading.